# React Native iOS Debugging in Safari Missing on M1

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, safari-web-inspector

I'm used to debugging my React Native (0.63.2) app using Safari's dev tools. I got an M1 Mac Mini last week and have since been unable to get the console or source tabs to show anything from the iOS simulator. Not sure if this is related to the new machine, or if I missed a setting. Any ideas?

I usually do Develop > Simulator > JSContents from Safari, and everything would show up fine. I can get logs in the terminal, but Safari's devtools are much easier to manage.

[image: Safari devtools and terminal]
[image: Safari toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and using the "Safari Technology Preview" from https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/ worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Glad to have my Safari logging back.